# matrix of special form

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have come across this matrix

\begin{equation*}
A_{m,n} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1} & a_{2} &  a_{3} \cdots & a_{n} \\
a_{2} & a_{2} & a_{3} \cdots & a_{n} \\
a_{3} & a_{3} &a_{3}\cdots & a_{n}\\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
a_{n} & a_{n} & \cdots & a_{n} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

where, also, $a_{1} \geq a_{2} \geq a_{3}...\geq a_{n}>0$.

Is this a special matrix, used anywhere else? Does it have any special properties - e.g. some result on eigenvalues etc...?

Comment: I don't think they have very nice properties in that setup. If you look at the case $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&b\end{bmatrix}$ The eigen values are $\frac{a+b \pm \sqrt{a^2-2ab+5b^2}}{2}$. They are distinct but they don't simplify to something nice.